# Plugin for users to create their own ads like Google Adsence

Tags: plugins, customization, ads

Does any one know of a plugin to allow users to create ads on a format like Google Adsense (title, some text and a link). ?

Something that may require some customization may do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "Users" do you mean registered users or visitor to yoour site?
For the first one I use [wordpress-multiple-user-ad-management](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-multiple-user-ad-management/), with some customized code since there a few options that I don't use. Also the text links options that the plugin have only allow users to create a title and the link for the ads (no other text or description for the ads).

The plugin offers the option for text ads, image ads(but images are hosted externally, user place the source link for the image) and a Paypal option for users to place a Donate button

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant registered users (Authors and Editors)

Comment: Well that plugin may give you a easy start, also you can customize the text links to look like you mentioned, title, some text and a link